# javascript recast .toSource options ignored

Tags: javascript, jscodeshift

I am trying to transform and reformat this javascript code:

```
if (name == "c") {b();}
```

using this recode plugin:

```
  return j(file.source)
    .find(j.Identifier)
    .forEach(path => {
      j(path).replaceWith(
        j.identifier(path.node.name.split('').reverse().join(''))
      );
    })
    .toSource({quote:'single'});
```

as saved here https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/994b660144d9e065906dc41bc14c9c39/c3910178f527d57de5422a0ddce9e515a460182d

I want to get the following output:

```
if (eman == 'c') {
  b();
}
```

but the `{quote:'single'}` option is ignored, and I am not sure that there is an option to force indent on if body on new line.
Is this a bug with astexplorer, recode or I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `.toSource()` uses `recast.print()` which tries to retain original formatting. `prettyPrint()` will respect more options:

```
var rc = require('recast');
rc.prettyPrint(ast, {quote:'single'}).code
```